# Algorithm that gets the largest sorted sub array from an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to do something in C and I need an algorithm that returns the largest dimension wise sorted array contained in another array. So, for example if I have the following array:

```
A[5] = {5, 2, 3, 1, 4}
```

it should return:

```
2, 3, 4
```

and I can't think of any efficient implementation. Got any ideas? Thank you. :)

Comment: This is called longest increasing subsequence problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is known as "[longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)".

An algorithm utilizing [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) can be [found here, with a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938833/find-longest-increasing-sequence). It has optimal asymptotic complexity of `O(nlogn)`.

The basic idea is, that you keep track of the best possible last element (or rather the index thereof) for a subsequence with length `i`. When you process the next element, you check the array `m` to see whether you have either

- found a better (i.e. smaller) possible last element for some length `i`
- otherwise you have found a longer sequence than you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the wikipedia page for Longest increasing subsequence:

```
 L = 0
 for i = 1, 2, ... n:
    binary search for the largest positive j ≤ L
      such that X[M[j]] < X[i] (or set j = 0 if no such value exists)
    P[i] = M[j]
    if j == L or X[i] < X[M[j+1]]:
       M[j+1] = i
       L = max(L, j+1)
```

This isn't C, but should be straightforward to code this in C.